# Работа с файлами в python

Tags: python, файлы

Как я могу реализовать открытие кода* картинки и вывод его в консоль на языке питон?

*если мы картинку откроем через нотепад
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Открываете файл в двоичном режиме. Читаете его. Выводите что хотите - символы, коды символов. Не очень понятно, что именно вы хотите получить в консоли.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите. Но просто открываете файл в двоичном режиме, читаете, выводите в нужном формате:

```
filename = '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/data/moon.png'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(' '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x:02X}', data[:20])))
```

Вывод:

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 00
```